# Spring: Hibernate insert null pointer exception

Tags: spring, hibernate, insert, null, javabeans

I am new to Hibernate and am running into a null pointer exception when I try to do an insert into my "RunEntity" database.

Here is my entity class

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Lob;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TESTRUNS")
public class RunEntity {

private int ID;
private int testNumber;
private String testName;
private String environment;
private String source;
private String passOrFail;
private Timestamp date;
private byte[] resultFiles;


@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue
public int getID()
{
    return this.ID;
}
public void setID(int ID){this.ID = ID;}

@Column(name="TestNumber")
public int getTestNumber()
{
    return this.testNumber;
}
public void setTestNumber(int testNum){this.testNumber = testNum;}

@Column(name="TestName")
public String testName()
{
    return this.testName;
}
public void setTestName(String testName){this.testName = testName;}

@Column(name="Environment")
public String getEnvironment()
{
    return this.environment;
}
public void setEnvironment(String enviro){this.environment = enviro;}

@Column(name="Source")
public String getSource()
{
    return this.source;
}
public void setSource(String src){this.source = src;}

@Column(name="PassOrFail")
public String getPassOrFail()
{
    return this.passOrFail;
}
public void setPassOrFail(String pOrF){this.passOrFail = pOrF;}

@Column(name="Date")
public Timestamp getDate()
{
    return this.date;
}
public void setDate(Timestamp dates){this.date = dates;}

@Lob
@Column(name="ResultFiles")
public byte[] getResultFiles()
{
    return this.resultFiles;
}
public void setResultFiles(byte[] file){this.resultFiles = file;}

}
```

I use beans to setup the database in my Applications class

```
import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
 import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@ComponentScan
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "web_application" });
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setAnnotatedClasses(RunEntity.class);
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}


@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}

@Bean
public BasicDataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:mem://runDb");
    dataSource.setUsername("sa");
    dataSource.setPassword("");
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public DbUtil dbUtil()
{
    DbUtil dbUtil = new DbUtil();
    dbUtil.setDataSource(dataSource());
    dbUtil.initialize();
    return dbUtil;
}

public Properties hibernateProperties()
{
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
    return prop;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Object[] sources = { Application.class, NightlySchedule.class };
    SpringApplication.run(sources, args);
}
}
```

Here is my DAO class

```
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

 @Repository
public class RunDao {

private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Autowired
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

public void insert(RunEntity run) {
    Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(run);
    session.getTransaction().commit();

}

public List<RunEntity> selectAll() {
    Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(RunEntity.class);
    List<RunEntity> run = (List<RunEntity>) criteria.list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    return run;
}

}
```

and here is my dbUtil class

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
 import java.sql.Statement;

 import javax.sql.DataSource;

 public class DbUtil {

private DataSource dataSource;

public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return dataSource;
}

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

public void initialize() {
    DataSource dataSource = getDataSource();
    try {
        Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement
                .executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE Run (ID INTEGER IDENTITY,TestNumber INTEGER NOT NULL, TestName varchar(50) NOT NULL, ENVIRONMENT VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, Source VARCHAR(50), Date TIMESTAMP, RESULTFILES BLOB)");
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at web_application.RunDao.insert(RunDao.java:26)
at web_application.IndexController.index(IndexController.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1720)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Comment: Share the error stack trace for a better understanding

Comment: I am guessing the `Session` is `null`. Where is the `@Transactional` demarcation that is going to create the transaction? Unrelated but you are using boot and you're configuring a lot of defaults that come out of the box (such as the datasource and hibernate properties)

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Ive been going off of this tutorial http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-hibernate-session-factory-annotation.jsp and replacing xml files with @ notation, but the tutorial never mentions transactions.  Ive been looking around but cant really find a good tutorial that includes that notation.  Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be that your currentSession may be null. Can you show the code where you call the insert method?

1. You should call the insert method on the service object, which is injected properly either by auto wiring or
2. If the service object is created using new, you can use the @Configurable along with AspectJ compile-time weaving to inject your objects